# How to use multiple decorators on an async function?

Tags: python, decorator, discord.py

I'm working with the discord.py module to try to set up a bot. Writing commands in the module looks like:

```
@bot.command()
async def test_function(ctx):
    await ctx.send('test')
```

I want to apply another decorator to one of these command functions, but just doing the following:

```
def second_decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        print('wrapper activated!')
        func()
    return wrapper

@second_decorator
@bot.command()
async def test_function...
```

Doesn't appear to work. As far as I can tell, the second decorator isn't taking effect at all-- 'wrapper activated!' is never printed.

Switching the order of the two results in `TypeError: Callback must be a coroutine.`, and from what I can see of the documentation on multiple decorators, that's not the correct format regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you decorate a function, you're doing so because you want to call the decorator on the function and use the result of the decorator instead of the function definition. `bot.command` does do that, but more importantly it registers the function as a callback inside the bot itself.  A pseudocode version would look something like

```
def command(self, callback, **options):
    if not valid(callback):
        raise error
    comm = Command(callback, **options)
    self.commands[comm.name] = comm
    return comm
```

So by the time the second decorator is called (decorators evaluate bottom to top), the callback has already been registered with the bot. `test_function` will refer to `wrapped`, but the callback registered with the bot will not.

You're having trouble ordering your decorators the other way because `command()` requires that its argument (the return value of second_decorator, `wrapped`), be a coroutine (an `async def` function).  Here's how I would write `second_decorator`

```
def second_decorator(coro):
    print("function wrapped")
    @functools.wrap(coro)  # Important to preserve name because `command` uses it
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('wrapped function called')
        return await coro(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```